# Counting unique ids within nested array using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following nested array and I'm trying to count how many items with unique `ids` there are. In the array below the count should be 2.

Array is of type `List<SolData>` it comes from Realm

```
class SolData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var uid = "";
    @objc dynamic var id = "";
}

extension SolData: ListDiffable {
    func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {
        return uid as NSObjectProtocol
    }

    func isEqual(toDiffableObject object: ListDiffable?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? SolData {
            return uid == object.uid
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Print of the array.

```
 (
    [0] SolData {
        uid = sdasd;
        id = jmX3;
    },
    [1] SolData {
        uid = gfd;
        id = jmX3;
    },
    [2] SolData {
        uid = hgfd;
        id = jmX3;
    },
    [3] SolData {
        uid = terw;
        id = jmX3;
    },
    [4] SolData {
        uid = fgg;
        id = GFdda;
    }
)
```

I tried to use `map` in the following way

```
var count = 0;
var prevId = "";

let uniqueSols = diff.sol.map{ (s) -> Int in
  if s.id != prevId {
    count = count + 1;
    prevId = s.id;
  }
  return count;
}

print(uniqueSols);
```

But I get the following error.

> SWIFT RUNTIME BUG: unable to demangle type of field '_transform'. mangled type name is 'q_7ElementSTQzc'
>   2018-10-27 14:26:08.793528+0300 App[23634:611928] SWIFT RUNTIME BUG: unable to demangle type of field '_transform'. mangled type name is 'q_7ElementSTQzc', _transform: ())

Comment: What is the array you are starting with? and what are `jmX3` and `GFdda`? And what is the field `_transform`? Do make your question easy to reproduce in a playground

Comment: Added more code. There is no _transform field. It seems like a strange error to me.

Comment: What are `ListDiffable` and `Object` ?

Comment: Do you want to know the unique elements or just the count of them? `map` is for turning `n` input elements into `n` output elements. To turn `n` input elements in `1` output element (the count would be just one output), you'd use `reduce` instead.

Comment: Why the down vote? I keep coming to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce your code, I am going to mock the `SolData` class and add an initializer to make instantiation easier:

```
class SolData {
    var uid: String = ""
    var id: String = ""

    init(uid: String, id: String) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.id  = id
    }
}
```

Let's create a few of instances:

```
let zero  = SolData(uid: "sdasd", id: "jmX3")
let one   = SolData(uid: "gfd",   id: "jmX3")
let two   = SolData(uid: "hgfd",  id: "jmX3")
let three = SolData(uid: "terw",  id: "jmX3")
let four  = SolData(uid: "fgg",   id: "GFdda")
```

And group them in an array:

```
let array = [zero, one, two, three, four]
```

To get only instances that have unique ids, let's use [`reduce(into:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce) :

```
let uniqueIds = array.reduce(into: Set<String>(), { $0.insert($1.id)})
```

The count property of `uniqueIds` is the number of unique ids in `array`:

```
let uniqueIdsCount = uniqueIds.count  //2
```

---

If you want an array of instances with unique ids, use the following:

```
let instancesWithUniqueIds = array.reduce(into: [SolData]()) { accumulator, element in
    if accumulator.allSatisfy({ $0.id != element.id}) {
        accumulator.append(element)
    }
}
```

`accumulator.allSatisfy({ $0.id != element.id})` maybe replaced by `accumulator.contains(element)` and making `SolData` conform to `Hashable`.

Comment: Dude! Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hey @Carpsen90 I keep coming to this but I have one more question related to the above. I have a different part of the app where I use a `for each` loop and `append` solutions to a `var arr: [SolData] = [SolData]();`. When I try to reduce that array it gives me the following error `Cannot assign value of type 'Set<AnyHashable>' to type '[SolData]'` Why doesn't the above reduce work in this case?

Comment: @Ando That would have been more appropriate for new question, but I've added some code to give you an array of unique instances, instead of what the original question which asked for: the count of unique ids.

Comment: Thanks, so much! I think it's a nice addition to the answer because the two are commonly used; besides I can do a count on the reduced results from the second part of your answer, now. Thanks for this again!